# Custom Path for a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

i developed a plugin (the backend at least) and now i want to add a frontpage to my blog.
the url should look something like this

```
http://www.mywordpressblogalsoroot.com/mypluginname/param1/param2
http://www.mywordpressblogalsoroot.com/mypluginname/param1/
http://www.mywordpressblogalsoroot.com/mypluginname/
```

all this three urls should point to a plugins function or a php site with a loop, i dont know.
the params should be readable , i think with `get_query_var`

i played a bit with the following:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','gamecard_insertMyRewriteRules');
// Adding a new rule
function gamecard_insertMyRewriteRules($rules) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(gamecard)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&gamecardslug=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function gamecard_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'gamecardslug');
    return $vars;
}
```

something is happening, but i stuck a bit.

somebody can give me a pointer how to get all this done?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well this one is tricky.

```
function my_plugin_query_vars($vars) {
    // add mypluginname to the valid list of variables
    $new_vars = array('mypluginname');
    $vars = $new_vars + $vars;
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_plugin_query_vars');
```

this will tell WordPress to accepts GET variables with the name mypluginname.
so now you can process requests like

> http://www.example.com?mypluginname=param1

We add an action on parse_request which gives us first change to parse given request before WordPress does.

```
function my_plugin_parse_request($wp) {
    // only process requests with "mypluginname=param1"
    if (array_key_exists('mypluginname', $wp->query_vars) 
            && $wp->query_vars['mypluginname'] == 'param1') {
        my_plugin_custom_function($wp);
    }
}
add_action('parse_request', 'my_plugin_parse_request');
```

Then we need to add a hook in WordPress rewrite system and then create a rule that tell WordPress to forward all requests to

> http://example.com/mypluginname/param1

to

> http://www.example.com?mypluginname=param1

with this code

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_plugin_rewrite_rules');

function my_plugin_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $new_rules = array('mypluginname/param1' => 'index.php?mypluginname=param1');
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

this should get you going :)
so i hope this helps.