# Custom rewrite, url path with parameters to a page

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm developing a plugin, that should display content according to two optional parameters in the URL. The following URL should all be treated by the plugin:

```
/pluginpage/
/pluginpage/value1/
/pluginpage/value1/value2/
```

Now I have put in place these things:

- A page with a shortcode `[myplugin]` and the URL `/pluginpage/`

  - The shortcode that displays the content taking the parameters from the `$_GET` variable
  - The plugin works if the URL looks like `/pluginpage/?param1=value1&param2=value2`
- Two rewrite rules in place, that match the three URL patterns to the page with the shortcode

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(pluginpage)/(.*)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&param1=$matches[2]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^(pluginpage)/(.*)/(.*)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&param1=$matches[2]&param2=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

The rewrite rules work, but not as expected. When navigating to `/pluginpage/value1/` or `/pluginpage/value1/value2/` the page with the shortcode is displayed, but there is a redirect to `/pluginpage/` and the parameters are lost during the redirect.

There is a missing piece that tells wordpress to not redirect from `/pluginpage/value1/` to `/pluginpage/`. What exactly is missing?

Or might there be a better approach by mapping the URLs directly to the plugin without using a page and a shortcode?

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7895/custom-path-for-a-plugin) is quite similar, but the answers are lacking important details, and therefore were not helpful in my case.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work fine with slight modifications. Taken from here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-content-4787

First off, I moved the rewrite rules to `init` and modified the regex to match parameters optionally:

```
function wse_414800_rewrite_state_city() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(pluginpage)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=pluginpage&state=$matches[2]&city=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(pluginpage)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=pluginpage&state=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'wse_414800_rewrite_state_city');
```

And, to be able to retrieve our custom query params I've added a function to register custom tags.

```
// Register query parameters for state and city
function wse_414800_register_query_param() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%state%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'wse_414800_register_query_param' );
```

And later on, you can retrieve the parameter either in your shortcode or in a page template using `get_query_var()`

For your query: "Or might there be a better approach by mapping the URLs directly to the plugin without using a page and a shortcode"

You can use a Page template as an alternative, here is an example for registering and using page template: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-content-4554)

Further it depends on what type of plugin you're building, if it's for internal use you can choose either of the options shortcode or template, but if you plan to publish the plugin IMHO a Gutenberg block or shortcode would do better.

```
function wse_414800_show_state_city_cb( $atts ) {

    $state = get_query_var('state');
    $city = get_query_var('city');

    return "State: " . esc_html( $state ) .", City: " .esc_html( $city );
}

add_shortcode( 'show_state_city', 'wse_414800_show_state_city_cb' );
```

You could utilize the plugin like Query Monitor to check what/how the rewrite rule is working.

[image: Query Parameter - Rewrite rule match]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will apply your recommendations, and hopefully get it work.

Comment: I'm still getting the redirection from `/pluginpage/value1/` or `/pluginpage/value1/value2/` to `/pluginpage/`, and I don't find any difference between your solution and mine that could explain it.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Did you try saving permalinks after adding the code? Because the code definitely works fine on my local test server.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer the main difference between @Kumar's solution and yours, is that he used the **query var** `pagename`, whereas yours used `name`, which would work, *if you actually have a regular post with the slug `pluginpage`*. If you didn't have that post, but you had a Page (post type `page`), then that explains why the redirect happened, i.e. you used the wrong query var in your rewrite rule. So as Kumar said, try flushing the rewrite rules by simply visiting the Permalink Settings admin page.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @SallyCJ

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Hey, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi Kumar, unfortunately, there is still a missing piece. After @SallyCJ's comment, I tried again with a post instead of a page, but I was not able to make it work. Maybe your answer is complete in the general case, and the problem is on my side? I don't know.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Page with slug `pluginpage` should've done the job, strange it doesn't works for you. Maybe try the solution on a different site or server and see if the fix works at all for you. This way you would be able to confirm if there is an issue with the site.

Or you might wanna check the fix with default theme and all the plugins disabled if that's possible for you.